# Sanity Test Case Writing

Tags: testing, automation, testcase, manual-testing

What is the difference in writing test cases and writing Sanity test cases for sign up of any website? Could anyone please let me understand by giving few test cases or example of Sanity test cases for sign up page of any website?

Comment: What even is a sanity test case? Is this a specific tool? A specific *kind* of test?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Sanity testing is the subset of regression testing and it is performed when we do not have enough time for doing testing. Sanity testing is the surface level testing where QA engineer verifies that all the menus, functions, commands available in the product and project are working fine.

Comment: This question is off-topic on SO, but https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_(software)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sanity tests by name suggests the case that validate if the application is sane. 
For example in context of sign up of a website, you may have the following tests as sanity:

1. Sign up option is available on login page.
2. Clicking "Sign up" redirects to proper , sign up form.
3. Clicking Sign in does not re-direct to "Sign up" form.
4. Submitting "Sign up" form goes successful, with out crash.
5. User signed up, is able to login.

The above are more then enough for a sanity test.
But for detailed testing you may include following tests in addition to the above one.

1. Signing up again, with same user id, is not allowed.
2. Sql injection is restricted.
3. Once signed up, user is allowed to sign in from multiple devices / browsers, without need to sign up again.
4. Cancelling mid-way sign up(half-filled form), is allowed.
5. Only the mandatory fields in form(if blank) should block the sign up.
6. Blank form sign up should not be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Sanity tests are done to check quickly whether application is behaving properly or not. It should not be very time consuming testing and is done in quick manner when you do not have enough time for testing.

Sanity tests does not have any specific tests cases and mostly done without test cases.

Answer (score 1):

For sanity testing , Just need to check straight forward flow of application whether it is working or not. Sanity testing give confidence to team that some of direct error, Exception not getting on Work flow.

Answer (score 1):

For an example, you wanna buy new car.

So when you are taking Test Drive that is called your **Sanity Check**

After one year of using that Car, When you are sharing your experience, that's called **Detail Test**

So Sanity check is basically overall check of all the links and UI, where Details Test cases are checking each and everything about the page with Negative and Positive Scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Every software testing services company follow the process of creating test cases before starting the feature testing. Sanity Testing is done when as a QA we do not have sufficient time to run all the test cases. Sanity test should be done only if QA team is running short of time, never use this for regular releases. Theoretically, this testing is a subset of Regression Testing.

Sanity test cases for validating Sign Up functionality quickly:

1. Sign up option is available on the login page.
2. Clicking "Sign up" redirects the user to appropriate sign up form.
3. User is able to fill details in all the mandatory fields of sign up form.
4. User is able to submit "Sign up" without any error.
5. User is able to access the account by using the credentials provided during sign up.

Regression test cases for 'Sign Up' form cover some other areas also:

1. Verifying sign up on all compatible OS and browsers
2. Cross Scripting is handled properly for all the fields on Sign up page.
3. Verifying that user is unable to sign up again with the same details.
4. Verify the behavior when sign up is in mid-way
5. Verifying that user is unable to sign up by leaving mandatory fields blank(This needs to be checked by leaving every mandatory field blank).
6. Appropriate error message w.r.t the field should be displayed on leaving any field blank.
7. Verify all the boundary values for text and numeric fields.

Answer (score 0):

Sanity test in first to check sin up function.
TO check validation all field.
To check the sin up button on click work is yes and no.
TO all field enter After the submit button on click that time check cress.
To submit button on click direct home page to check.